# Dropdown menu effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a [site](http://beta.jointviews.com/)  .As you can see there's a menu item called Digital Marketing. The item has a submenu called Digital Marketing Consultancy.i want the submenus like in any other websites with the dropdown effect like when we hover the menu item the submenus dropsdown.
eg : like the menu [here](http://itsquad.us/).

I have tried giving

```
 .sub-menu{display:none;}
 .sub-menu:hover{display:block;}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyy7e61o/) .how can i make it like the menu effects in other sites.Please help.Thanks!!
**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyy7e61o/4/)**

Comment: Really good article here -> http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Dropdown-Menu-in-HTML-and-CSS

Comment: You really don't need any JavaScript/jQuery to achieve want you want here. There are very many tutorials and guides on the web to make a dropdown menu. This [will](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) help you maybe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure css solution is CSS(3) transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/9gjbfvwy/

use width and height 0, with overflow hidden.
Use CSS3 transitation to set them to auto.

See fiddle (it's your code, with 3 additions)

```
ul.sub-menu{height:0;width:0;overflow:hidden;}
.menu-item:hover ul.sub-menu{background:orange;width:200px;height:50px;}
ul.sub-menu {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: this worked but when i added another submenu item with a submenu it went wrong again .. here is the updated fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/wyy7e61o/4/

Comment: .menu-item:hover > ul.sub-menu Just added > to the css, with that, your will only animate the ul which is a direct child of the menu-item and not the child of an child etc.
And don't use fixed height then like the 50px in my example, but just auto height

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bkau4Lz0/ is the working sub-submenu example, only thing is, you need to think what exactly you want with the menu and then just play with height, width, position relative/absolute etc

Answer (score -1):

`.sub-menu` is your submenu, so you need to fire your hover on your main menu item, not on your submenu item.

Add this to your css:

```
ul#menu-main li ul.sub-menu{
    display:none;
}

ul#menu-main li:hover ul.sub-menu{
    display:block;
}
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wyy7e61o/1/

Comment: this worked but when i added another submenu item with a submenu it went wrong again .. here is the updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/wyy7e61o/4

Comment: It's none animated, like asked

Answer (score -2):

You should initially hide all the submenus and show them when hovering the parent menu.
Like

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
.menu-item:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Check Updated fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/wyy7e61o/6/

Comment: your jsfiddle is link to the original jsfiddle, please fix it.

Comment: updated fiddle link!

Comment: his worked but when i added another submenu item with a submenu it went wrong again .. here is the updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/wyy7e61o/4

Comment: the fiddle given in your comment doesn't have my css code! check out this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wyy7e61o/6/

Comment: It's none animated, like asked

Comment: @d1m5n: but he didn't ask for any animation! I can find word "Animation" only in your comments!

Comment: The demo site you provided was an animated site, but hope that you found what your looking for